# Payment gateway development - Handling and Processing parameters/keys PHP to Json, Json to PHP

Tags: php, json, jsonresponse

I have written a Payment processor.php file to receive parameters from an ecommerce system then post to a PSP (Payment Service Provider), then this Json response from the PSP will be decoded, verified and Keys converted and parsed to the ecommerce system this way:

```
header("Location: ".$hosturl."orderprocessor? 
orderid=$custref&sig=".$_POST['SessionId']);
```

Before giving out item in cart to users.

$hosturl has been defined as 
       $hosturl="localhost:8080/ekp/"; 
in another file

The result I get each time I do cart checkout with "Payment processor.php" file is just a white screen. I am supposed to see the PSP's interface to receive user's card details instead.

The PSP's URL is;  " https://developers.paystack.co/reference#paystack-standard-x" I am following the cURL PHP sample for reference.

kindly assist if corrections are spotted in my code.

This is my Payment processor.php file:

```
<?php require_once 'includes/config.inc.php' ?>
<?php
$parameters = array();

if (isset($_POST['amount'])) { /* came the LMS; about to send data to 
Paystack */

$sig=hash_hmac("md5","amount=".urlencode($_POST['amount']).
                 "&currency=".urlencode($_POST['currency']).
                 "&orderid=".urlencode($_POST['orderid']), $KEY);

$parameters['UserName']=$username;
$parameters['Password']=$password;
$parameters['reference']=$_POST['orderid'];
$parameters['Amount']=($_POST['amount'] * 100);
//should change SessionId' to be named reference
$parameters['SessionId']=$sig;
$parameters['SessionKey']=$encryptionKey;
$parameters['DL']="activ_purchase";
$parameters['ServerURL']=
base64_encode("http://localhost/nse/ecommerce/paystack.php");
$parameters['UserURL']=
base64_encode("http://localhost/nse/ecommerce/paystack.php");
$parameters['AccountNumber']=$accountnumber;
//$parameters['UserDeclinedURL']=
base64_encode($hosturl."externalpaymentcancel? 
orderid=".$_POST['orderid']);

  //  print_r($parameters);
  $cart=$_POST['cart'];
 //  var_dump($cart); die;               
 $cartitems=objectToArray(json_decode($cart));

            foreach ( $cartitems['items'] as $item  )
            {
                    $productName=$item['description'];
                    $quantity=1;
                    $price=$item['price']['amount'];
                    $parameters['Reference4']=$productName." Qty 
".$quantity." @ $".$price."\r\n" ;
            }
// created parameters for Paystack $postdata here

$postdata =  array('email' => 'customer@gmail.com',
                   'amount' => $parameters['Amount'],
                   'reference' => $parameters['reference'],
                  );
//$url = "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize";

//My codes for $ch here

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$paystackUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode($postdata));  //Post 
Fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = [
'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_*****************************',
'Content-Type: application/json'];

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

//My code for $ch ends here

//starting to setup redirect url
if ($result) {
$request = json_decode($result, true);
//print_r($request);
foreach ($request as $input) {
if($input ['data']['reference']){
  $sst=['data']['reference'];
  break;
}
}

header('Location:'.$result['data'] 
['authorization_url'].$parameters['SessionId'].$sst);
}
//Use the $result array to get redirect URL paystack

//var_dump($result);
}
else { 

$result = array();
$url = 'https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/'.$_GET['reference'];
// print_r($parameters);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt(
$ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_*****************************']
);
$request = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($request) {
$result = json_decode($request, true);
// print_r($result);
if($result){
  if($result['data']){
    //something came in
    if($result['data']['status'] == 'success'){

header("Location: ".$hosturl."orderprocessor? 
orderid=$reference&sig=".$_POST['SessionId']);
//echo "success";
      // the transaction was successful, you can deliver value
      /* 
      @ also remember that if this was a card transaction, you can store 
the 
      @ card authorization to enable you charge the customer 
subsequently. 
      @ The card authorization is in: 
      @ $result['data']['authorization']['authorization_code'];
      @ PS: Store the authorization with this email address used for this 
transaction. 
      @ The authorization will only work with this particular email.
      @ If the user changes his email on your system, it will be unusable
      */
      echo "Transaction was successful";
    }else{
      // the transaction was not successful, do not deliver value'
      // print_r($result);  //uncomment this line to inspect the result, 
to check why it failed.
      echo "Transaction was not successful: Last gateway response was: 
".$result['data']['gateway_response'];
    }
  }else{
    echo $result['message'];
  }

}else{
  //print_r($result);
  die("Something went wrong while trying to convert the request variable 
to json. Uncomment the print_r command to see what is in the result 
variable.");
}
}else{
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" 
content=\"5;URL=$hosturl"."externalpaymentcancel?orderid=$custref\"> 
</head><body style=\"text-align:center; font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><p><img 
src=\"/nd/repository/EKP000000414.jpg\" alt=\"Activ logo\" /></p> 
<p>Unfortunately, we were unable to process your payment.</p><p>The 
response from your financial institution was &quot;$declinedmessage&quot; 
</p><p>You will be redirected to the LMS shortly.</p></body></html>";
}  
//echo $payresult;

//if ($payresult=="1") {
      //header("Location: ".$hosturl."orderprocessor? 
orderid=$custref&sig=".$_POST['SessionId']);
//echo "success";
    //} else {
//echo "fail";
//echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" 
content=\"5;URL=$hosturl"."externalpaymentcancel?orderid=$custref\"> 
</head><body style=\"text-align:center; font-family:'Open Sans', Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif;\"><p><img 
src=\"/nd/repository/EKP000000414.jpg\" alt=\"Activ logo\" /></p> 
<p>Unfortunately, we were unable to process your payment.</p><p>The 
response from your financial institution was &quot;$declinedmessage&quot; 
</p><p>You will be redirected to the LMS shortly.</p></body></html>";
//header("Location: ".$hosturl."externalpaymentcancel?orderid=$custref");
  //  }
}

function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Why you get a white screen? How to convert json to PHP? Have you checked your servers error log? Please do some proper debugging and find out where it goes wrong instead of just posting a bunch of code and hope that we'll debug it for you.

Comment: this line should cause the error `orderid=$custref&sig=".$_POST['SessionId']);`, see the string highlighting, probably a missing `"`

Comment: Before you post code for us to look at, please remove the droves of uncommented lines. This is a mess and is really hard to read. While you're at it, make sure your code is properly indented.

Comment: @Kaddath - You're correct. I was looking at the wrong line. There are so much irrelevant stuff in the code which makes it really hard to read :-/